# Underscore template in HTML generating mysterious 404 errors

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, underscore.js

Okay, I have this underscore template (simplified version), rendered from `_template.html.erb`, in my Rails app, somewhere on the page:

```
<script type="text/html" id="mytemplate">
<div class="foo">
  <img src="{{= my_variable }}" />
</div>
</script>
```

Then I render it like this, elsewhere, when required:

```
// change it to mustache-style because of defaults clashing with erb
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate: /\{\{\=(.+?)\}\}/g,
  evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};

options = {
  my_variable: '/foo/bar/baz.img'
}

compiled = _.template($("#mytemplate").html());
$(compiled(options)).appendTo("#wherever");
```

This, in theory should work just fine and it does, except errors like this started popping up in server logs and elsewhere, browsers 404-ing on URLs like: `http://example.com/{{=%20my_variable%20}}`, or `http://example.com/foo/{{=%20my_variable%20}}`.

Now, my **hunch** is that it has something to do with the fact that it's an `img` tag and somehow the browser tries to `GET` it from the page, even though it's wrapped in `script` tags, but I have no idea why on earth. This is one of the recommended methods by many people for embedding underscore templates into HTML. And I can't attribute it to older browsers and/or robots either because server logs show these are real people using the latest Chrome etc.

Edit: after a bit more investigating, 1. it only happens to a few people (unique IPs) 2. all of them are using the latest version of Chrome. So maybe it's an extension gone haywire?

Any ideas?

Comment: Try changing the `type="text/html"` to something non-existent `type="x-template"` (or anything really)

Comment: @SimonBoudrias nope, that's not it. I already changed it from `text/template` to `text/html`, hoping that would resolve it, and now to `x-template` and it still happens a few times a day.

Comment: Hey @KTamas, I edited my answer below with 2 possible workarounds

Answer (score 0):

You must change the `type="text/html"` to something non-existent like `type="x-template"` (or anything really)

This normally works if the cache is cleared and all.

If nothing really does it, then you could use **external templates** (files that you load). But if you want to keep them inline, then **escape the problematics chars** (with internal JS char encoding). This will be parsed the same by JS, but won't get caught by HTML parser.

You can use this tool: http://mothereff.in/js-escapes (uncheck the "*only escape non-ASCII and unprintable ASCII characters*" box)

That's what it could looks like:

```
<script type="text/html" id="mytemplate">
<div class="foo">
  \x3Cimg src="{{= my_variable }}" />
</div>
</script>
```